# How can we turn off device screen when front camera is covering in android?

Tags: java, android

How to turn off device screen when front camera is covered with user finger, Can anybody tell how it will possible programmatically in android

Comment: @Rotwang Can you answer any question.

Comment: This post shows no research effort, and you're just asking for code. Which is not the aim of this site. Please do your homework and only come searching for help when you are not able to make your code work properly.

Answer (score 1):

For doing this, you need to keep camera on always. This will drain a lot of battery. If you still want to implement the same then you can check the image being formed in camera. If user covers the camera with finger/anything then image should be pure black. You can check color of all pixels of the image and then lock the screen accordingly.

Better way to do it will be by using proximity sensor and light sensor. Using camera consumes lot of battery and might not be accurate.

Comment: Thanks alot for giving me idea.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not late to the party but it seems what you looking for is the proximity sensor. Take a look at this https://github.com/williambout/react-native-proximity